# positive, negative, zero numbers without using if elif else

Tags: python

Use dictionary statements that asks user to enter a number and tell if it is positive, negative, or zero. A user needs to enter a number and identify if its positive negative or zero. Without using if elif and else

Comment: Homework assignment? What have you got so far?

Comment: I haven't gotten anywhere yet. I know how to do it using if elif else but i don't know how using dictionary statements. @Schnitte

Comment: What do you mean by "dictionary statements"?

Comment: 'def a (b):
    c = {
        0 : "zero",
        1 : "one",
        2 : "two"
    }
    return c.get(b, "nothing")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = 0
    print(a(b))'
then when i run it it will show zero
this was the example given
now i need something like this in finding if the number is positive, negative, or zero.
@Vlad

Answer (score 1):

If you perform arithmetic with Python's True or False they have effective values of 1 and 0 respectively. Therefore:

```
dict_ = {0: 'Zero', 1: 'Positive', 2: 'Negative'}
i = int(input('Enter a number: '))
print(dict_[(i != 0) + (i < 0)])
```

Of course you could just use a list for the output strings but OP seems to need to use a dictionary for no obvious reason